# Django elasticsearch dsl term and phrase search is not working

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I used two packages (i.e. `django-elasticsearch-dsl==7.1.4` and `django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf==0.20.8`) to add a search engine to my Django project.
The model which I indexed in elastic is:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(_('created time'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(_('updated time'), auto_now=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('accounts.UserProfile', verbose_name=_('profile'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    approved_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('approved user'), blank=True, null=True, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='article_approved_users')
    approved_time = models.DateTimeField(_('approved time'), blank=True, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(_('image'), blank=True, upload_to=article_directory_path)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(_('content'))
    summary = models.TextField(_('summary'))
    views_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('views count'), default=int, editable=False)
    is_free = models.BooleanField(_('is free'), default=True)
    is_enable = models.BooleanField(_('is enable'), default=True)

    tags = TaggableManager(verbose_name=_('tags'), related_name='articles')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', verbose_name=_('categories'), related_name='articles')
    namads = models.ManyToManyField('namads.Namad', verbose_name=_('namads'), related_name='articles', blank=True)
```

I used the following document for indexing my `Article` model:

```
html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="whitespace",
    filter=["lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
    char_filter=["html_strip"]
)


@registry.register_document
class ArticleDocument(Document):
    title = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
        }
    )

    tags = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            "name": fields.TextField(
                analyzer=html_strip,
                fields={
                    'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
                    'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
                }
            )
        }
    )
    categories = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': fields.IntegerField(),
            'title': fields.TextField(
                analyzer=html_strip,
                fields={
                    'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
                    'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
                }
            )
        }
    )
    namads = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            "id": fields.IntegerField(),
            "name": fields.TextField(
                analyzer=html_strip,
                fields={
                    'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
                    'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
                }
            ),
            "group_name": fields.TextField(
                analyzer=html_strip,
                fields={
                    'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
                    'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
                }
            )
        }
    )

    class Index:
        name = settings.ARTICLE_INDEX_NAME
        settings = {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ArticleDocument, self).get_queryset().filter(
            approved_user__isnull=False,
            is_enable=True
        ).prefetch_related(
            'tags',
            'categories',
            'namads'
        )

    class Django:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'summary']
```

And finally used the following viewset to search on it's result (based on [this document](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage_examples.html#suggestions).)

```
class ArticleSearchViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    """

        list:
            Search on all articles, ordered by most recently added.

            query parameters
            -  Search fields: 'title', 'summary', 'tags.name', 'categories.title', 'namads.name',
                'namads.group_name' . Ex: ?search=some random name.
        retrieve:
            Return a specific article details.

    """
    serializer_class = ArticleDocumentSerializer
    document = ArticleDocument
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        IdsFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilterBackend,
        DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
        SuggesterFilterBackend,
    ]
    search_fields = (
        'title',
        'summary',
        'tags.name',
        'categories.title',
        'namads.name',
        'namads.group_name'
    )
    filter_fields = {
        'id': {
            'field': 'id',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of id field in this example,
            # to `range`, `in`, `gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        },
        'namads': {
            'field': 'namads',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `pages` field in this
            # example, to `range`, `gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        },
        'title': "title.raw",
        'summary': 'summary',
        'categories': {
            'field': 'categories',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `pages` field in this
            # example, to `range`, `gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        },

        'tags': {
            'field': 'tags',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `tags` field in
            # this example, to `terms, `prefix`, `wildcard`, `in` and
            # `exclude` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_TERMS,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_PREFIX,
                LOOKUP_FILTER_WILDCARD,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_EXCLUDE,
            ],
        },
    }
    # Suggester fields
    suggester_fields = {
        'title_suggest': {
            'field': 'title.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_TERM,
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
                SUGGESTER_PHRASE,

            ],
            'default_suggester': SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            'options': {
                'size': 10,  # Number of suggestions to retrieve.
                'skip_duplicates': True,  # Whether duplicate suggestions should be filtered out.
            },
        },
        'tags_suggest': {
            'field': 'tags.name.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
            # 'options': {
            #     'size': 20,  # Override default number of suggestions
            # },
        },
        'categories_suggest': {
            'field': 'categories.title.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_TERM,
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
                SUGGESTER_PHRASE,
            ],
        },
        'namads_name_suggest': {
            'field': 'namads.name.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
        },
        'namad_group_name_suggest': {
            'field': 'namads.group_name.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
        },

    }
    ordering_fields = {
        'id': 'id',
        'title': 'title',
        'summary': 'summary',
    }
    # Specify default ordering
    ordering = ('-id', )
```

And my document serializer is:

```
class ArticleDocumentSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        document = ArticleDocument
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'summary', 'namads', 'categories', 'tags']
```

Every thing works fine except when I'm using `term` and `phrase` search with following query parameters:

`?title_suggest__phrase=fi`

`?title_suggest__term=fi`

In the url `localhost/api/v1/blog/articles-search/suggest/` but in both cases the results are the same like the following:

```
{
    "title_suggest__term": [
        {
            "text": "fi",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 2,
            "options": []
        }
    ]
}.
```

And also I'm pretty sure that I have `First article` in my index and when I use completion suggester every thing works fine (i.e. `?title_suggest__completion=fi`) and it returns results.
Am I missing something? I want to add term and phrase search to my project. How can I fix this problem (Term and phrase results are 0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my suggester configurations. First of all for `term` and `phrase` suggest we do not need completion fields (i.e. `'suggest': fields.CompletionField()`) and we just need to declare our field in our `Index`, something like:

```
title = fields.TextField(
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer=html_strip)
        }
    ) # which goes in documents.py
```

and just add the following to any fields to enable `term` and `phrase` suggest:

```
suggester_fields = {
        'title_suggest': {
            'field': 'title',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_TERM,
                SUGGESTER_PHRASE,

            ],
        },
    } # Which goes in views.py and search view suggester_fields
```

and to see the related suggest result we should send query parameters like `?title_suggest__term=something` or `?title_suggest__phrase=something`.
Finally if we need to add completion to suggester fields too we should add it with some other key like:

```
suggester_fields = {
        'title_suggest': {
            'field': 'title',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_TERM,
                SUGGESTER_PHRASE,

            ],
        },
        'title': {
            'field': 'title',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
        },
    }
```

and now with this configs we have three type of suggestions on title field (i.e. `term`, `phrase` and `completion`). So if we want the whole result based on these three suggesters we should use three query parameters like:

`localhost/api/v1/blog/articles-search/suggest/?title_suggest__term=something&title_suggest__phrase=something&title__completion=something`

And do not forget to change the field config in your `Index`(In case we need completion suggester):

```
title = fields.TextField(
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer=html_strip),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
        }
    ) # Which goes in documents.py
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to customized this default ordering result based on some value in the column to bost first  # Specify default ordering
    ordering = ('-id', ) ????